# Finding the number of intersections of two curves, with rescritions.

Tags: polynomials, roots, problem-solving

> Let two variables $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ be defined by the curves 
>   \begin{align}
> x=\frac{-(ab+c)y^2+(a-m)y}{cy-m}\\
> y=\frac{-(ef+d)x^2+(e-m)x}{dx-m}
> \end{align}
>   Where $a,b,c,d,e,f,m\in\mathbb{R}$ and are all positive nonzero constants. Assume that $cy-m\not=0$, $dx-m\not=0$ and $x,y>0$. How many solutions are possible and what conditions on the coefficients are necessary to ensure that number of solutions?

I am confused what methods I can/should use to answer this question.

**Notes**

- To clarify what the question we are asking if we instead replace the system with $ax^2+bx+c=0$, the answer would be

  - If $a c<0$ there is one positive real root and one negative real root.
  - If $ ac>0$,$b^2 -4 ac> 0$ and $\dfrac{-b}{2 a}>0$ then there are two real positive roots.
  - If $ac>0$, $b^2 -4 ac=0$ and $\dfrac{-b}{2 a}>0$ there is one real positive root.
- Note sure what the appropriate tags are for this question so please feel free to edit the tags.
- References to papers or texts would also be appreciated.
- I am not looking for the explicit form of the solutions but the number of solutions.
- If you need any clarification feel free to ask.

Comment: Well, they're quadratic curves, so they are conic sections.  It's pretty clear that they can't intersect in more than four points.  One thing is sure, you can't have two circles.  Other than that, I don't know how to deal with this -- looks messy.

Comment: Yes, I accidentally hit <Enter>.  Fixed now.

Comment: Maybe solve for $x$ from one equation as saulspa says its quadratic.. and put in other equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular form of these equations allows us to make some simplifications. Let $z=x/y$. The two equations are equivalent to
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  z&=&\frac{-(ab+c)y+(a-m)}{cy-m},\\
  z&=&\frac{dx-m}{-(ef+d)x+(e-m)}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
We can rearrange to express $x,y$ in terms of $z$:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  y&=&\frac{mz+(a-m)}{cz+(ab+c)},\\
  x&=&\frac{(e-m)z+m}{(ef+d)z+d}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
(Note that each denominator is positive by assumption.) Now $z$ must satisfy the cubic equation
$$
  z(mz+(a-m))((ef+d)z+d)-(cz+(ab+c))((e-m)z+m)=0.
$$
So our task is equivalent to counting how many roots of this cubic are greater than $\max(0,1-a/m)$. In particular there are at most $3$. Probably it is possible to find exact criteria in terms of the constants by using the discriminant of the cubic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very elegant. One question that I still have is why I am looking the roots of the cubic that are greater than $max(0,1-\frac{a}{m})$, rather looking for roots of the cubic that are greater than $0$.

Comment: Also I am not aware that there was a relationship between the discriminant of the cubic and the number of positive real roots. I dosen't the discriminant only give information on the number of real roots?  I can use Sturm's Theorem to answer the question of the number of positive real roots. But I want to know if there is a relationship between the discriminant on the number of positive real roots.

Comment: @AzJ we must have $z>1-a/m$ to ensure $y>0$. I didn't mean that the discriminant alone would be sufficient, only that it might help. Sturm's Theorem might be simpler.